# Select in eloquent join laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to access the join table, and the getProducts() method was working if getting the data without select clause. How can i get the point_transaction->id without the select clause? (I'm getting the user table id)

**Controller**

```
$query = PointTransaction::join('users','users.id','=','point_transactions.user_id')->select('point_transactions.id as point_id', 'point_transactions.status as point_status')
```

**View**

```
<td>{{$pointTransaction->point_id}}</td>
<td>
    {!!'';$items = $pointTransaction->getProducts() !!}
     @foreach($items as $key => $value)
     {{$key}} : {{$value}}
     @endforeach
</td>
```

I've tried the following query:

```
$query = PointTransaction::join('users','users.id','=','point_transactions.user_id')->select('point_transactions.id as point_id', 'point_transactions.status as point_status');
```

and I'm getting error of Trying to get property of non-object for the above method of getProducts()

also I've tried the following:

```
$query = PointTransaction::join('users','users.id','=','point_transactions.user_id');

    if($where){
        switch($where){
            case "point_transactions.id":
                $query = $query->where('id', $value);
            break;
            default:
                $query = $query->where($where, 'like', '%'.$value.'%');
            break;
        }
    }

    $pointTransactions = $query->desc()->paginate($paginate)->get(['point_transactions.id as point_id', 'point_transactions.status as point_status']);
```

and I'm getting the following error:

ErrorException in Collection.php line 1032:
array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Comment: `->get()->all()`

Comment: You should use relationships, in your code it seems to be One-to-Many Relationship. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select is same in eloquent as well but you can also use get() method as select() like:

```
$query = PointTransaction::join('users','users.id','=','point_transactions.user_id')->select('point_transactions.id as point_id', 'point_transactions.status as point_status')
```

This can be used as following as well:

```
$query = PointTransaction::join('users','users.id','=','point_transactions.user_id')->get(['point_transactions.id as point_id', 'point_transactions.status as point_status']);
```

---

### UPDATE

Your mistake:

```
$pointTransactions = $query->desc()->paginate($paginate)->get(['point_transactions.id as point_id', 'point_transactions.status as point_status']);
```

`get()` and `paginate()` methods can't be used together. You have to use any one of them.

**get()** is used to show all results together.
**paginate(count)** is used to show given count of results per page.

I have already given an example of `get()`. You can use `paginate()` method just like that:

```
$pointTransactions = $query->desc()->paginate($paginate, ['point_transactions.id as point_id', 'point_transactions.status as point_status']);
```

As you can see above, I have just removed `get()` method from the end of the query and updated the `paginate()` method with your required fields.

[Laravel using paginate with only selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44193693/7109362)
[Laravel - Paginate and get()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19617149/7109362)

Comment: @telesid, Can you please look at my updated question? It's not working yet. Thanks

Comment: **updated my answer** ... Check it. You were actually mistaking `paginate()` and `get()` methods!!!

Comment: Thanks bro! Did it :D

Answer (score -1):

Because of same "id" column in two table. So you must specified the "id" in which table.

```
'point_transactions.id as point_id'
```