# Get paginated results that are also ordered using Laravels QueryBuilder

Tags: php, laravel

I want to retrieve posts ordered by the created_at date but I also want to paginate the results as well. So far I have tried the below:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

$posts = Post::paginate(10);
```

The above only returns 10 results and not ordered by the created_at date.

I want to retrieve 10 posts that are ordered by the created_at date. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `->get()` and `->paginate()` are both functions that execute a query, so Post::paginate() is running a new query and paginating all posts. To use paginate with any constraints write the query as you did in the first example and replace `->get()` with `->paginate($perPage)`

Comment: @ru501 Just replace the `get()` with `paginate(10)`. `paginate()` get all the data and put the limit and offset as per given/defined while calling pagination.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Paginate and get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616720/laravel-paginate-and-get)

Comment: Yeah, don't override your variables. If you have two instances of `$posts = Post::{method}();`, the 2nd one will override the first, unless the 2nd references the first, like `$posts = $posts->{method}();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the returned posts get overwritten is because you are reassigning the `$posts` variable. Take a look at the below to correct the issue.

Laravels QueryBuilder allows you to string multiple filters one after another.

In this case, you'll order your posts by the created_at date and then retrieve the results via the paginate filter. The paginate filter will replace `->get()`.

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 4):

**You can try like this**

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "If write both codes, It is overwritten" but the following should work:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `paginate()` instead of `get()`. Both fetch the data from the Database while only one difference is, paginate put a limit as per given as a parameter and put the limit and offset as required.

#### [Paginating Eloquent Results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results)

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

#### Print pagination links like:

```
{{ $$posts->links() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use paginate or simplePaginate like this

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

for details https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination